# Artin approximation for Banach rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

Let $B$ be an integral Banach ring, meaning it is complete with respect to a norm and it is an integral domain. Let $F$ be its fraction field. Let $\widehat{F}$ be the completion of $F$ with respect to the norm on $A$.

Is there an Artin approximation theorem for $F$
and $\widehat{F}$? Meaning solutions of equations over $\widehat{F}$ imply solutions of equations over $F$?

If it is not true in general, are there cases where it is true?